# Is there an action of the abelianization of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on lattices?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Since there is an action of the group $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and knowing that its abelianization is the group $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, is there a corresponding quotient action of this cyclic group on lattices as well ?

Comment: Every finite group acts faithfully on some lattice. In this special case you have an action on $Z^{12}$.

Comment: Obviously, but is it derived from the action of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and if so, how ?

Comment: $[SL(2,\Bbb{Z}),SL(2,\Bbb{Z})]$ contains the kernel of $SL(2,\Bbb{Z}) \to SL(2,\Bbb{Z/(12)})$, what is natural is the action of $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})$ on $\Bbb{Z/(12)}^2$ but it doesn't factor through $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})^{ab}=SL(2,\Bbb{Z/(12)})^{ab }$. A non-natural action of $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})^{ab}$ is to send $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c& d}$ [to](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf) $\pmatrix{ 1 & ((1−c
2)(bd+3(c−1)d+c+3)+c(a+d−3))\\ 0 & 1}\in SL(2,\Bbb{Z/(12})$. Otherwise there is the natural but non-faithul action of $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})^{ab}$ on $\Bbb{Z/(2)}^2$.